# Problem with writing a basic function to produce number of multiples

Tags: functions, memory, coding-style

I'm working my way through [Wolfram Challenges](http://challenges.wolfram.com), the first question was Ok but tripped myself up on the second question. I have a basic function which takes a positive integer n and returns the number of multiples of both 3 and 5 up to n. It works for relatively smaller sets but after a point it gets stuck. So I am having trouble formatting it to be a proper written function. In searching for an answer myself, people online have made all sorts of elegant solutions for this popular programming problem but my question is far simpler in that I don't know why my function is failing.

```
f[n_Integer]:= Length[If[Mod[#, 15] == 0, #, Nothing] & /@ Range[n]]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "my function is failing"? It works but it is awkwardly slow for large `n` (it stops working though if `n` is so large that `Range[n]` cannot be stored in memory, though).

Comment: The failure is that it stops working if n is so large as the range specification does not have appropriate bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `IntegerPart`

```
f[n_Integer?Positive] := IntegerPart[n/15]
```

Comment: As it was the case with my code, range specification in your code also does not have appropriate bounds so it stops if n is very large. Try f[10000000000000000000000000].

Comment: @Ilker That seems unlikely, since there are no `Range` objects at all here. Have you been `Clear`ing the definition of `f` between tests, just to make sure?

Comment: I tried `f[2^1000000 7^1000000 11^1000000] // AbsoluteTiming` and timing is `0.0418793sec`

Comment: The code is perfectly fine ..Sorry, it was my bad...I was running bunch of codes when I tried yours ..I think I I had forgotten to clear the previous definitions.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are looking for

```
f[n_Integer?Positive] := Quotient[n, 15]
```

`Quotient[n, m]` is basically equivalent to `Floor[n/m]`.

The problem of your function is that it needs $O(n)$ memory and $O(n)$ integer operations for a task of complexity $O(1)$. Moreover, using `Nothing` leads to unpacking of [`PackedArray`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array)s which is also slowing things down.

Comment: Simple and eloquent; many thanks! And many thanks for all your very enlightening explanations.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the constant-time mathsy answer is the best. But a much more idiomatic way to do precisely what you were doing is:

```
Length@Select[Range[n], Mod[#, 15] == 0 &]
```

or

```
Count[Range[n], _Integer?(Mod[#, 15] == 0 &)]
```

This will have the same memory problems but is much faster: on my machine with `n=100000`, with averages taken over one hundred runs, your way takes an average 0.142167 seconds, while the two ways above are average 0.0826457 and 0.0940736 respectively.

Faster yet is:

```
Total[Boole[Mod[#, 15] == 0] & /@ Range[n]]
```

which is positively snappy at 0.00402328 seconds; it's even faster than `Count[Mod[Range[100000], 15], 0]`.

But the winner I've found which still operates on a list is

```
Total[1 - Unitize[Mod[Range[n], 15]]]
```

which is 0.00113424 seconds: that's a full 125 times speedup over your one for `n=100000`.

Comment: Try also `n - Total[Unitize[Mod[Range[n], 15]]]`...

Comment: Length@Select[Range[n], Mod[#, 15] == 0 &], Count[Range[n], _Integer?(Mod[#, 15] == 0 &)], Total[Boole[Mod[#, 15] == 0] & /@ Range[n]], and Total[1 - Unitize[Mod[Range[n], 15]]] stop if n is so large. I get the following message: Range called with 0 arguments; between 1 and 3 arguments are \
expected.

Comment: @Ilker For which $n$ are you seeing this? You can expect the code to stop working eventually, because it's still having to create a gigantic list and operate on it.

Comment: @PatrickStevens, say, when n=10^100, it stops working. But those of Okkes and Henrik  work perfectly.  For example, that of Okkes,  f[n_Integer] /; n > 0 := IntegerPart[n/15], for n=100^1000, produces the results with a timing of 0.000037.

Comment: Of course it stops working in that situation. You have asked your computer to hold in memory more numbers than there are atoms in the universe.

Comment: @Ilker, let me give you something to ponder on. You can use `ByteCount[]` to reckon out the amount of bytes needed to store something. For example, `ByteCount[2*10^9]` says that 16 bytes are needed to store that integer. Now think about what you were trying to do, and consider the number of bytes needed for all those numbers, and then compare with the size of your computer's memory and hard disk space.

Comment: Dear @J.M, I understand what you are trying to explain. Patrick pointed out the same problem. What I needed was a function that can produce the multiples of 3 and 5 regardless of the size of n, i.e., without facing the range specification and memory problem. I have greatly benefited from every single answer posted here for my question.